# PSQL подстановка литерала в sql запросе

Tags: postgresql, psql

Согласно [документации](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/10/app-psql#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) пытаюсь делать подстановку литерала-переменной в sql запрос, но psql не согласен и указывает на ошибку перед :'username'

```
\set username 'foo'
\set basename 'bar'

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test()
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
    SELECT application_name FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE usename=:'username' AND datname=:'basename';    
$BODY$;
```

Как правильно оформить подстановку в таком контексте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Подстановка переменных не будет выполняться, если SQL литералы или идентификаторы заключены в кавычки. Поэтому конструкция ':foo' не превратится во взятое в кавычки значение переменной (и это было бы небезопасно, если бы работало, так как обработка кавычек внутри значения переменной была бы некорректной).

[`Dollar-quoted String Constants`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html) вида `$BODY$...$BODY$` - это частный случай строкового литерала. Поэтому подстановка не выполняется просто потому что не должна.

---

Вероятно вам нужны параметры функции?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test(text, text)
    RETURNS setof text
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
AS $BODY$
    SELECT application_name FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE usename=$1 AND datname=$2;
$BODY$;

select test(:'username', :'basename');
```

---

> но psql не согласен и указывает на ошибку перед :'username'

psql'у без разницы. Он не валидирует синтаксис.

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
>   СТРОКА 5: ...lication_name FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE usename=:'username..

Это отвечает сама СУБД